# how does swap environmental URL work exactly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, production-environment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently used swap environmental URL to upgrade my Elastic Beanstalk application, using two environments. I have a CNAME record at a different URL mapped to the beanstalk URL. I tried then to push to the production environment(which now was at the test URL), and then swapped again, but this seemed to not work correctly.

I would expect the swap to map the test environment to the production URL, meaning that when I was previously pushing to the test environment to test, now I should push to the production environment, then swap to make another zero-downtime upgrade. This can be very confusing, so I was hoping someone can shed light on this, as there seems to be adearth of information about Elastic Beanstalk and swapping URLs.

Comment: Be aware that DNS records might take some hours to propagate over to DNS servers accross the globe. Might that be the case?

Comment: @Viccari - Pretty sure Beanstalk domain swapping is internal to AWS (and I suspect run through Route53 but I can't prove it). Basically AWS just maps app1.elasticbeanstalk.com to app2's ELB... I think. It's a completely opaque process. Hence DNS cache expiration wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @diogenes - you might try [the zero downtime CLI deployment script](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) AWS has in the docs. If the swap still fails with their own example, it suggests something is wrong with the push process, instead of the swap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[URL swap](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) is a simple operation of exchanging CNAMEs between two Green/Ready environments. It has nothing to do with Route 53 (or any other DNS). The only thing that it does is just exchanging of two CNAMEs. For example, you have one environment `foo-1` with CNAME `foo-1.example.com`, and another one `foo-2` with CNAME `foo-2.example.com`. After swap operation environment `foo-1` will respond at `http://foo-2.example.com`.

This operation is required in order to deploy a new version of your application with zero downtime. Your DNS will point your `www.example.com` to `foo-1`, which is changed on fly by a-few-seconds CNAME swap. Users won't see any delays, provided your application knows how to share resources (a database, for example).

You can take a look at [jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-beanstalk-maven-plugin/) (I'm a developer). This Maven plugin does exactly this CNAME swap operation in a fully automated manner.

Comment: If it has nothing to do with route53, why then is there a warning when swapping that says: `Swapping the environment URL will modify the Route 53 DNS configuration, which may take a few minutes. Your application will continue to run while the changes are propagated.`

Comment: Yeah so uh CNAME is DNS.

Answer (score 7):

Please be careful here about which "Swap URL" feature is being discussed...  If you are referring to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk "Actions" | "**Swap Environment URLs**" feature, my experience is that this feature has *nothing* to do with DNS and *nothing* to do with Route 53.

From what I can see, **AWS EB Swap URL's** simply swaps the public-facing URL's of your beanstalk environments... Keeping you from having to change your DNS at all.

Example:

Let's assume you have two EB environments:

"quality" with an EB URL of "quality-qq443224.elasticbeanstalk.com"

"quality-patched1" with an EB URL of "quality-patched1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

If you choose the "quality-patched1" instance and choose "Swap Environment URL's" with your "quality" instance...  All that will happen is they **will now be listed as**:

"quality" with an EB URL of "quality-patched1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

"quality-patched1" with an EB URL of "quality-qq443224.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Therefore your EXISTING DNS CNAMEs (assumed to be in Route 53 and assumed to be pointing at /quality-qq443224.../) do not have to change at all... They will be directed to your **new** patched instance.

Comment: So it *does* have everything to do with DNS.

Comment: However, it seems that if your Route 53 is pointing at a load balancer, then you do need to swap it to the new one…

Comment: Rich, I was thinking the same thing. If you set up your domain's A record as a Route 53 Alias to a specific Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer, I'm pretty sure that the CNAME swap will have no affect on that DNS record. Only if you used a CNAME DNS record and pointed to yourself.elasticbeanstalk.com would it have any affect. Am I correct? The workaround is to simply update the Route 53 Alias manually to the new environment's ELB once it's up.

Comment: hi, can you pls  tell me what will  happen if I have "production" env running 3 instances (load balanced) and I try to swap it with "production-2" enviroment running 1 instance (also load balanced)?,   ...do I need to tell it to spin up 2 extra instances before I do the swap, or will AWS take care of that ?  Thank you

Comment: Elad Nava is exactly correct.  With the alias pointing to the Elastic Load Balancer that I had set for the A records, the swap had no affect.  I had to go in and manually add the Elastic IP of the new instance (after I had done the Swap URL's) to the A records in Route 53 for my domain.

Comment: @RichBradshaw, EladNava, you're both right. To be clear, if you have a Route 53 Alias pointing to an EB Load Balancer, then the Swap URL's functionality does nothing at all, so you only need to re-point the alias to the new ELB. The (small) downside of this setup is that a DNS change can be a bit slower (to propagate) than EB swapping URLs. Although more details on the trade-offs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Comment: @AlexB No, the DNS of either public domain isn't altered. It's only these private domains that are swapped.